# How to verify if a dedicated server is really dedicated?

Tags: dedicated-server

I ordered a dedicated server 1 month ago and I want to make sure my server is dedicated and not a VPS or Shared server. Are there any tools I can verify that my server is running on bare metal and that I am the only user?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

First, you should trust your hosting provider. If you think they sold you a VPS, maybe you should reconsider this provider.
Just to make sure you have a dedicated you can try this:

**Does the command `esxtop` work ?**

This tool is used to check performances on Virtual Machines

**Check the network interfaces.**

Run the command `ifconfig`. If you see something like this:

```
venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  P-t-P:127.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:99999 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:99999 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:126223307 (120.3 MiB)  TX bytes:2897538 (2.7 MiB)

venet0:0  Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:6x.xxx.xxx.xxx  P-t-P:6x.xxx.xxx.xxx  Bcast:6x.xxx.xxx.xxx  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1400  Metric:1
```

you are probably have a VPS since venet0 is telling that this server is being an OpenVZ VPS. 
Note: This is not 100% fool proof, some VPS like Xen have an eth0.

**Check devices/system:**

Run `lspci` and `dmesg` as root. If you see something like:

```
VMWare SVGA device
acd0: CDROM <VMware Virtual IDE CDROM Drive/00000001> at ata0-master UDMA33
da0: <VMware Virtual disk 1.0> Fixed Direct Access SCSI-2 device
```

Then you are using a VPS.

**Check if some files exists:**

If it's a VPS running OpenVZ they'd have a file called `/proc/user_beancounters`. View http://wiki.openvz.org/Proc/user_beancounters for more details.

Look if `/proc/vz` or `/proc/vz/veinfo` exists (for OpenVZ) or `/proc/sys/xen, /sys/bus/xen or /proc/xen` (for Xen)

Check if `/proc/self/status` has an `s_context` or `VxID` field.

If one of these file exists, then you have a VPS.

**IP lookup:**

You could do a reverse IP lookup to check to see if any other websites are hosted on the same IP.

**Check Memory:**

Run `lspci` and look for RAM memory: `Qumranet, Inc. Virtio memory balloon`. Then you have a VPS.

Comment: I didn't see any Vnet** or VM or anything else that looks like I have a VPS. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you are virtualized under OpenVZ or Virtuozzo the file /proc/user_beancounters will exist

Comment: Totally great answer! But now its been 2 years already. May be there are some changes in VPS technologies? Can we still rely this methods? Please.

Comment: @夏期劇場 I would say yes ... adapters and devices might change but they will never the same name as the REAL adapters or devices. I would double check the name of the adapters on the web to make sure.

Answer (score 19):

To augment @Book Of Zeus' answer, if you are running under KVM you will see things like:

```
root# grep 'model name' /proc/cpuinfo 
model name      : QEMU Virtual CPU version 0.15.0
root@nscache1a:~# dmidecode -t system | grep Manufac
       Manufacturer: Bochs
root# grep QEMU /proc/scsi/scsi
  Vendor: ATA      Model: QEMU HARDDISK    Rev: 0.15
  Vendor: QEMU     Model: QEMU DVD-ROM     Rev: 0.15
```

And under XenCenter:

```
root# dmidecode -t system | grep -e Manu -e Prod
       Manufacturer: Xen
       Product Name: HVM domU
```

Comment: is it mean i have a VPS if it say: command not found?

Comment: @Tech4Wilco: No, it just means you don't have dmidecode install. Do you have apt or yum or something like that, that you can install dmidecode with?

Comment: oh thanks, i thought it came with the OS by default

Comment: I am getting -`root@(none):~# grep QEMU /proc/scsi/scsi
  Vendor: ATA      Model: QEMU HARDDISK    Rev: 0.12` . Does that mean it is a VPS

Answer (score 4):

You may just want to execute the command `dmidecode -t system` and check the output of the "Manufacturer" which will give you an idea about the machine you are working on.

Comment: The OP is only interested to know and make sure that what he's/she's paying for is also what is he/she using. In this case, he/she must have a dedicated server since that is also what he/she paid for. Now, there are a lot of ways to verify the server remotely and for me, the simplest way is to execute the command `dmidecode -t system` as what I mentioned in my previous message. But it is assumed that the underlying OS is GNU/Linux or other *Nix variants.

Answer (score -1):

Enter the command "df -h". If you see a virtual file system type, then that indicates you're on a virtual machine. For eg. "vzfs" is the Virtuozzo file system virtualization technology developed by Parallels, Inc.

---

What I see on my virtual private server:

```
# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs              40G  3.7G   37G  10% /
none                  512M  4.0K  512M   1% /dev
```

Comment: Here is what it looks like on one of my VPS: `/dev/sda3        18G   16G  1.3G  93% /`

Answer (score -2):

To confirm that your server is running on dedicated hardware, you can use command-line tools. Check the processor information with commands like "lscpu" or "cat /proc/cpuinfo" to see if it reflects the dedicated specifications you ordered. Additionally, inspect memory details using "free -h" and disk information with "df -h" to ensure resources align with a dedicated server. Lastly, review the server logs and hosting provider documentation for any indications of virtualization or shared environments, ensuring you are the sole user on the server.

Comment: All of this would be the same inside a VM.

Comment: How do you think this adds to the accepted answer?

Comment: This answer adds very little to the accepted answer. Please consider adding to it or withdrawing it.